# Sentinel-2 images OFFSET: Should negative resulting OFFSET values be 0 (NODATA) or 1?

Tags: offset, satellite-image, sentinel2, no-data

I’m processing Sentinel-2 images outside of snap and have a more general question about the new OFFSET values in Baseline 04.00 that I hope you may help me understand.

While comparing images between the current Baseline 04.00 and earlier Baseline versions I subtract the BOA_ADD_OFFSET value or RADIO_OFFSET_VALUE from the Baseline 04.00 images depending on product. This sometimes leads to, as expected, negative values in the resulting raster.

My question is: What is the correct way to present these values if clamping them to a floor of 0? Should they be regarded as NODATA (value 0) - Implying missing or faulty data?
Or should they be viewed as a minimum value (like 1)? The reasoning being that these have a registered value that is out of bounds, but assumed to be approximately 0.

I’d be grateful if you can enlightnen me on how to best reason about the negative values or refer me to a source that better describes how the offset works as the Sentinel-2 Products Specification Document doesn’t supply enough context for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has now been answered by Jan on the ESA Step Forum:
https://forum.step.esa.int/t/info-introduction-of-additional-radiometric-offset-in-pb04-00-products/35431

> I would suggest that they should be regarded as NO DATA (value 0).
> This would at least flag them as unreliable. This is based on my
> understanding of negative reflectance values being linked to the
> Atmospheric Correction processing step. And thus they are an unwanted
> contribution to the output. So making them 0 identifies them as
> non-nominal, and helps serve as an avoidance measure. Or a flag of
> doubt. Giving them a value of 1 would potentially attribute them some
> relevance, and may serve to confuse.